# Initialize sdk in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run

Per documentation [Initialize the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=4#initialize-sdk) I will need to generate `New Private Key` and feed that to the init process at the service.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("New Private Key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://blah.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Is there way at IAM level add trust to `Cloud Run` so it will allowed to access `Firebase  services`? I would like to use `admin.credential.applicationDefault()` when I run in the `Cloud Run`.

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

Just need a clarification may be I am misreading and it is already doing that.

Comment: I am thinking you can use the implicit credentials in effect when Cloud Run executes ... and then use this recipe .... https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=4#initialize-without-parameters

Comment: It seems it is included in Cloud Function if you deploy via cli.  I will give a try.

Answer (score 1):

By implementing the Firebase Authentication you can achieve what you want to do:

First you will need to setup [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) in your project and service.

1. Enable in the Cloud IAM API for your  project.
2. Authorize the Cloud Run credentials to sign tokens. (This can be done by visiting the IAM & admin page in the Google Cloud console, and granting the Service Account Token Creator role to the Default compute service account.)

But in theory it is included in Cloud Functions, but just to be sure you can make the second step, but depending on the needs of your application it might or not be an overkill if you just want a simple authentication.

Comment: it is a bit different what I need. I feel it should be simpler. I just do not like the idea to have file generated and pass to Cloud Run.

Answer (score -1):

Tested instance and it seems running from Cloud Run env SDK was able pull `admin.credential.applicationDefault()`! Amazing how it was simplified! Rolling all my apps to Cloud Run!!!  Having experience with Azure/AWS, GCP by far too friendly! Kuddos to GCP!

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?